# Bedeutung und Beugung von "einer" als Pronomen

Tags: pronoun, genitive, einer

Diese Woche habe ich ein Meme gesehen, auf dem zu lesen war: *Ein Mikrobleistift **einer** meiner Schüler.*

Dieses "einer" kann ich als Nichtmuttersprachler überhaupt nicht verstehen. Hätte es nicht "**eines** meiner Schüler" bzw "**von einem** meiner Schüler" heißen sollen?

Gemeint wird hier, glaube ich, ein und einziger Schüler, oder? Und wenn es um den Bleistift *eines Schülers* geht, der übrigens zur Gruppe meiner Schüler gehört, woher kommt diese Endung -er?

Ich hätte natürlich verstanden, wenn der Satz etwa "Einer meiner Schüler ist krank" wäre, was aber nicht der Fall ist.

Handelt es sich einfach um einen Fehler, oder habe ich etwas wirklich missverstanden?

Comment: *Mikrobleistift* ist mir noch nie begegnet. Ist ein [Druckbleistift](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Druckbleistift) (mir auch unter *Feinminenbleistift* bekannt, so aber nicht in Referenzen auffindbar)  gemeint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Richtig ist

> ein Mikrobleistift *eines* meiner Schüler

Zunächst muss man erkennen, dass *eines meiner Schüler* eine Verkürzung von *eines Schülers meiner vielen Schüler* ist. Zudem ist es das Genitivattribut zu *ein Mikrobleistift*. Und da *Schülers* im Genitiv Maskulinum steht, muss auch das Pronomen *eines* im Genitiv Maskulinum stehen.

Alternativ geht natürlich auch die Konstruktion mit *von* und Dativ:

> ein Mikrobleistift *von einem* meiner Schüler

Comment: Diese Verkürzungsthese wird hier immer wieder vertreten. Aber *ein Schüler meiner Schüler* wird doch nie benutzt, um *einer meiner Schüler* auszudrücken; wie könnte also dieses die Verkürzung von jenem sein? Außerdem ist die Endung *-er* von *einer* unerklärlich, wenn eine Verkürzung von *ein Schüler* vorläge.

Comment: Nach einigem Überlegen halte ich das im Beispiel verwendete *eines* für das Indefinitpronomen (in Frage käme aber auch noch der Zahlenwert). Das Gegenstück *keines* sperrt sich gegen die Neutralisierung der hier formulierten Verkürzung.